# Spring Cloud Config - Could not resolve placeholder

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

## Background

I am trying to add centralized configuration support to a medium sized spring based application. I recently made it Bootiful :D It can now run as a jar in an embedded tomcat though with the same old configuration files as before. So next I want to get rid of the filesystem property-files.
I have the Config server setup and working, backed by a git repo containing the configuration.

## Problem

During startup my application indicates that a property source is found on the config server.

```
2016-12-15 13:16:19,759 [admin] [ INFO] [] config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator - Fetching config from server at: http://localhost:8888
2016-12-15 13:16:20,186 [admin] [ INFO] [] config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator - Located environment: name=myapplication, profiles=[default], label=develop, version=b065758e8ea56ff9f9e8773f263da7705b6aac29
2016-12-15 13:16:20,188 [admin] [ INFO] [] bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration - Located property source: CompositePropertySource [name='configService', propertySources=[MapPropertySource [name='http://configserver@gitserver/config.git/application.properties']]]
```

The problem is mapping to fields annotated with `@Value` eg.

```
@RestController
public class DemoController {

    @Value("${my.property}")
    private String myProperty;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String myproperty() {
        return myProperty;
    }

}
```

Stacktrace:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'my.property' in string value "${my.property}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
...
```

Will not map the property even though a request to `http://localhost:8888/myapplication/default`responds with:

```
{
    "name": "myapplication",
    "profiles": [
        "default"
    ],
    "label": "develop",
    "version": "b065758e8ea56ff9f9e8773f263da7705b6aac29",
    "state": null,
    "propertySources": [
        {
            "name": "http://configserver@gitserver/config.git/application.properties",
            "source": {
                "my.property": "Test successful"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

## What I have tried

### Clean slate

If i go to https://start.spring.io/ and generate a project with the cloud config client dep and set it up to fetch the same properties as my other project everything works as intended. Which leads me to think there is some dependency in my bigger project thats is in conflict with how the properties are resolved. If i debug the project during startup i can se that the properties from my configserver are in the spring `Environment` but does not end up in the PropertyPlaceholder.

### ConfigurationProperties

Mapping the properties from the configserver to a POJO annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties` works around the problem. But im not in control of all `@Value` annotated classes so i cannot use this approach for libs from other teams.

## ...so

Is there some way to make sure the cloud-config properties are mapped *before* `@Value` annotations are resolved?

Comment: Post the full stack trace. The properties from the cloud-config server are resolved very early on in a special bootstrap context. So they are available. I suspect that you are doing something in your configuration you should be doing.

Comment: It was too long to plase in the question.
see: http://pastebin.com/DSreYFth

Comment: This is a fairly standard thing to do. It might be helpful to see your build file and dependencies or a small sample that reproduces the problem. Config server values are added to the Environment before the normal application context is loaded.

Comment: Judging from the stack trace you have configured your own `PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer`. You don't need it remove it.

Comment: @M.Deinum I defined that bean in an attempt to solve the issue, made no difference. I get the same error when i remove the bean :( I have some older xml configuration files that I've not yet converted. Could this interfere with where in the startup sequence the environment is mapped to the PropertySourcePlaceholder?

Comment: Also make sure that there is no `<context:property-placeholder />` in your xml configuration. Or set the `ignore-unresolved-placeholders` attribute to `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was (as M.Deinum pointed out) to remove a defined `<context:property-placeholder />` in one of the older xml configuration files. In my case it was imported from another imported xml configuration file. Once i replaced the import of "another.xml" with java config the issue was resolved.

Thanks @M.Deinum !

**AdminConfig.java:**

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource(value = {
        "classpath:/legacy-conf/applicationContext.xml"
})
public class AdminConfig {

    //... Bean definitions
}
```

**applicationContext.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    ...other config...
    <import resource="classpath:another.xml"/>

</beans>
```

**another.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    ...other config...
    <context:property-placeholder />
</beans>
```