# @Value not working in Spring @Configuration

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, properties

Need help, where is the issue?

I have a configuration class which is loading properties as

**WebConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value={"classpath:application.properties"})
class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
       return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

I have another configuration class where I am trying to use the properties as

**MyServerConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
class MyServerConfig {

    @Value("${server.url}")
    private String url;
...
}
```

**application.properties**

```
server.url=http://localhost:8080/test/abc
```

But getting:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'server.url'.

Don't know what is missing here? Any thoughts?

Comment: Why did you make the method `propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` in class `WebConfig` `static`?

Comment: Can you post your configure **application.properties** file.

Comment: @Jesper Just trying one of the solution that I found in google, and it is not working even if you remove the static or completely remove the method

Comment: @SamDev Its already in the question, check again

Comment: Take a review this URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41164983/spring-cloud-config-could-not-resolve-placeholder

Comment: Do you have mixed XML/Java config? If so, check that you don't have a `context:property-placeholder` left.

Comment: Please take a look at [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your problem can only be reproduced with all necessary information. At least your spring version

Answer (score 0):

Use the `@PropertyScan` annotation in the class where a certain property will be used:

```
@Configuration
@PropertyScan("classpath:application.properties")
class MyServerConfig {

    @Value( "${server.url}" )
    private String url;
}
```

Comment: Any error? "Not working for me" doesn't help me either to find the solution that suits you.

Comment: And it is just not working here, whereas in a similar way it is working in @Service class

Comment: Same error as mentioned in the question. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'server.url'

Comment: I think you mean either `@ComponentScan` or `@PropertySource` because there is no annotation named `@PropertyScan`

Answer (score 0):

For getting the values for your `@Value` variables, the `application.properties` is not needed to be configured in any special way because this file is always scanned. So remove the `@PropertySource` annotation and `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean.

These are used if you want to add other `.properties` files (e.g. `constants.properties`, `db-config.properties`).

So just remove those and try to run your application again

**Very important:**

1. Make sure you scan the class that uses the `@Value` annotation (If your BootApplication is in some package instead of the 'main' package, add the proper `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.my.project" })` annotation).
2. Make sure your `application.properties` is on your classpath.

**Bonus** If you are using spring profiles (e.g: `prod`, `dev`), you can also have `application-prod.properties` and `application-dev.properties` files that will be scanned and included depending on which profile you are running.